# Does protein benefit women the same way as men?

Tags: weightlifting, protein

How does protein help girls that work out at the gym? When I say workout I mean weightlifting not aerobic.

Comment: Are you assuming that consumption works differently for males and females?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes.That is my assumption

Comment: Because from start if a female trains like a male they won't gain the same benefits, in a 2 month period males could change drastically while females barely see a difference .

Comment: That is because of varying hormone levels. Nutrients still serve the same purpose in everyone.

Comment: Alec is correct.  Hormone levels are typically the determining factor.

Comment: Well thank you for the well received information :)

Comment: Of course! It's better to ask than continue not knowing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protein has various functions in our bodies, most notably for rebuilding muscle tissue after a workout.

In this, there is no difference between genders.

I suggest you read up on the cellular functions of proteins for yourself, as the question is so vague that a full answer would fill books.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein#Cellular_functions